# "Forgot password" and "forgot username" are separate issues - question erroneously marked as duplicate

Tags: discussion, status-completed, exact-duplicates

The question [How can I recover my Gmail account when I remember the password, not the username?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22778/how-can-i-recover-my-gmail-account) is really about an odd case where a user remembers his *password*, but not his *username*. I have suggested a title edit to reflect this.

There are other questions which are about people forgetting their Google *passwords*, which have been marked as a duplicate of this one, e.g. [What do I do if I forgot my Gmail password?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9217/what-do-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-gmail-password)

I suggest the duplicate marking is removed, so that we keep the *forgot username* and *forgot password* issues separate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good catch. I've reopened the question and approved your edit to the first question.

These things happen from time to time.

Comment: Great, thanks. However, at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9217/what-do-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-gmail-password there's still a message saying `Possible duplicate: How can I recover my GMail account?` Will that message eventually go away?

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal - Ah. It was closed before the [on hold] changes when the "possible duplicate" text was edited into the question. I'll edit it out.